# User creating multiple objects from one class during runtime -Java

Tags: java, object, runtime

So I have been looking around and reading up a lot of forums and the java documentation but I can't seem to get a solid solution for what I am trying to do.

Essentially I have a Module class as shown below:

```
/**
 * MODULE CLASS
 * This class will be the base for every Module inputed into the system
 * @author George
 */
public class Module {

//  -=VARIABLE DECLARATIONS=-
    private String moduleName; /* String variable to store the name of the module */
    private String moduleLeader; /* String variable to store the name of the module leader */
    
//  -=GETTERS=-
    public String getModuleName() {return this.moduleName;} /* Will return the name of the module */
    public String getModuleLeader() {return this.moduleLeader;} /* Will return the name of the module leader */
    
//  -=SETTERS=-
    public void setModuleLeader(String l) {this.moduleLeader = l;} /* Sets the name of the module leader to the inputed name */
    public void setModuleName(String n) {this.moduleName = n;} //THIS NEEDS TO BE ADDED TO DESIGN DIAGRAMS
    
//  -=CONSTRUCTOR=-
    /**
     * Constructor to make a new object for the module
     * @param n (NAME) - String input to set the name of the module
     * @param l (LEADER) - String input to set the name of the module leader
     */
    public Module(String n, String l) {
        this.moduleName = n;
        this.moduleLeader = l;
    }
}
```

On my GUI, each module is represented as its own button which upon clicking will take you to the module's page using CardLayout. I also have a button where the user can add a module, this is where my issue comes into place. Obviously a Module object would be defined as:

```
Module newModule = new Module("name", "leader");
```

But how would this allow more than one object to be created. The name of the module would come from user input so there is no way I can put the name of the object in the source code and from what I have read you cannot set the object name using a variable.

Lets say for example, during runtime, the user would want to create two modules. One with the name of "Java" and one with the name of "Python". How would I go about doing this? Obviously the first object would be created just fine using the initialization above, but the name of the object would be stuck as newModule. But then it would not be able to create the second object as it cannot have two objects with the same name. I have spent some time trying to understand HashMaps to see if that could be of any use to me but quite frankly I find it quite confusing and again, I can't tell if that is the correct solution.

I hope I have worded this correctly and you can understand my problem. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What your questions about maps or list? I think a Map or List implementation can help you. You need create a Map/List and add new instances of module into Map/List, this way you can get all modules from this map or list, filter by name, filter by specific key... depends on your logic.

Comment: It's possible create a List<> or Map<> typed on specific object, example `Map<String,YourModuleObject> mapCanReceiveObjectModuleBySomeKey;` or `List<YourModuleObject> listCanReceiceObjectModule;`